# Can I set the value of an existing request attribute again?

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, request

I have a homepage in which I have a header, a sidebar, and a div tag. 
When the user clicks on "register", `Registration.jsp` is loaded into the div tag.

On successful submission of the registration form I want to forward it to the same page where I want to display a html "bookimages.html" in the div tag.

I tried setting an attribute value to do this.

This is my mainpage.css:

```
<body id="userprofilepage">
<% request.setAttribute("regisstatus",null); %>
<div>
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %><br>
</div>

<div id="mainsidebar">
<%@ include file="sidebar.html" %>
</div>

<div>
<%@ include file="priviledges.html" %>
</div>

<div id="contentarea">
<% if(request.getAttribute("regisstatus")==null)
{ %>

<%@ include file="bookimages.html" %>
<% } else if((request.getAttribute("regisstatus").toString()).equals("success")) { %>
            <%@ include file="Register.jsp" %>
    <% } else { %>

<h3>Sorry could not register.. Try again</h3>
<% }  %>
</div>

</body>
```

**jquery**

In my header I have a register button:

```
    $(function(){
    $("#register").click(function(){
        $("#contentarea").load("RegistrationServlet.jsp");
    });
});
```

...which is working fine. and calls RegistrationServlet.java:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Takin all parameters

          String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
          //System.out.println(fname);
          String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
          //System.out.println(lname);
          String mobileno = request.getParameter("mobno");
          //System.out.println(mobileno);
          String pwd = request.getParameter("password");
          //System.out.println(uid);
         // String cpwd = request.getParameter("password");
          //System.out.println(pwd);
          String email = request.getParameter("email");
          String off_add= request.getParameter("off_add");
          String perm_add = request.getParameter("perm_add");

          String[] r = request.getParameterValues("role");

          for(int i=0;i<r.length;i++)
          {
              System.out.println(r[i]);
          }
          ArrayList<Integer> role=new ArrayList<Integer>();

          for(int i=0;i<r.length;i++)
          {
              Integer r1=new Integer(RoleManager.getRoleid(r[i]));
            role.add(r1);
          } 
          /*for(int i=0;i<r.length;i++)
          {
              Integer r1=new Integer(RoleManager.getRoleid(r[i]));
              role.add(r1);
          }*/



         String g[]=request.getParameterValues("genre");
          ArrayList<Integer> genre=new ArrayList<Integer>();
          for(String i : g)
          {
              Integer g1=new Integer(GenreManager.getGenreid(i));
              genre.add(g1);
          }

        // creating user object 
          RegisteredUser uobj = new RegisteredUser();

        //setting values in RegisteredUser obect

          uobj.setFname(fname);
          uobj.setLname(lname);
          uobj.setPassword(pwd);
          uobj.setMobileno(mobileno);
          uobj.setPassword(pwd);
          uobj.setEmail(email);
          uobj.setOffadd(off_add);
          uobj.setPermadd(perm_add);
          uobj.setRole(role);
          uobj.setGenre(genre);
          uobj.setUid("abc2");

          //send user object to manger

          boolean suc=UserManager.createUser(uobj);
          System.out.println("user object created");
          if(suc) 
             request.setAttribute("regisstatus", "success");
          else
              request.setAttribute("regisstatus", "fail");
          RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/userprofilepage.jsp");
          rd.forward(request, response);


    }

}
```

But in my homepage, the request attribute is not being set. Can you help me identify the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the way you use the `.load()` function is not the correct way.

In your code, the `$("#contentarea")` div is counted on the server side for the first request and then no more. Your `.load()` function loads the result of ***RegistrationServlet.jsp*** into your div, but not refreshing the div according to it.

I thing you sholud do an ajax request on "RegistrationServlet.jsp", and as it succeeded refresh your page, or bulid the logics in ***RegistrationServlet.jsp*** as well so the `.load()` function call can remain the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..

But when i am forwarding my request to "userprofilepage.jsp" in my 'RegistrationServlet" then isnt my jsp being reloaded again???
Then at the time of reload it should be checking my attribute "regisstatus"...shouldnt it?

Comment: As I mentioned before <code>.load()</code> initiates an ajax request, loads the result into its selector. It does not refresh the whole page.